# Wait until last container of compose has succesfully finished on docker compose up?

Tags: docker-compose

I have a docker compose file, which startes multiple docker containers in an order.

When executing `docker compose up` I would like to wait until the last container has `sucessfully_completed`

The `--wait` option only seems to wait until the docker container is running or healthy, which is too early.

I could add another dummy container waiting for my last container to `sucessfully_completed` but this seems a bit odd.

How can I wait for my last docker container of my docker compose to be completed, when running a docker compose file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Comment: Actually it does not. The healthcheck is a tool to check if a container is up and running. I want to check if the last container of the docker compose up has completed and is not running anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a way to do this with `docker compose up -d`

One solution is to follow your `docker compose up -d` command with something similar to:

```
while ! [[ $(curl --fail --silent http://127.0.0.1:8080/healthcheck) == 'Success' ]] ; do sleep 3; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did use a dummy container:

```
  my-logically-final-container:
    container_name: do-stuff
    image: alpine
    ...

  finisher:
    container_name: wait-for-completion
    image: alpine
    healthcheck:
      test: exit 0
      interval: 2s
    depends_on:
      my-logically-final-container:
        condition: service_completed_successfully
```